# iPad mini won't turn on/charge

Tags: ipad, charging, power, shutdown

I have had my iPad mini for a long time, and it's been having issues for the past year. Whenever I let it completely loose power, it takes forever to actually turn back on. When I have it plugged in, it will power back on and show the apple logo on the white screen, and then shut back off. It does this a few times (like 5 or 6 times) before actually powering all the way on. Does anyone know what's going on or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, this is expected behaviour when your iPad battery is extremely low. Basically, the battery will need a certain amount of charge to allow your iPad to switch on, and a certain amount of charge to effectively boot up.

If your iPad mini works fine otherwise, then it's really probably just a case of not letting it get too low before placing it on charge.

Also, you need to ensure that you're connecting it to its original charger, or to a charger providing enough current to charge the iPad effectively. In the absence of doing this you may find the iPad takes a lot longer to charge before being able to boot it up again.

Finally, as you've had your iPad mini for a long time, the battery may have exceeded its expected charge cycle count. When this happens it won't maintain a charge for as long as you're used to and it will take a lot longer before it can reach a state of charge needed to work properly. Eventually, it will die altogether (although if it has enough charge then you can effectively use it while it's connected to a power source - but if it loses that state of charge, then even having it connected to a power source may not suffice).

Comment: The reason why I think it's weird is that it dies, I plug it in, it starts to power up, and then it dies again. That keeps happening where its plugged in for like 5 minutes and then it starts to power up only to die again before I've even touched it

Comment: Okay, does it eventually charge up and function normally? Also, how old is your iPad mini? Finally, have you tried using a different cable and charger?

Comment: It does eventually charge up, but it ends up taking about 2 hours for it to actually turn on and function. I think I've had it for about 5 or 6 years and I use an Amazon basics cable and a Samsung fast charge port normally, but I have tried multiple chargers and ports and it doesnt seem to help. I honestly think it's something I just have to deal with, but I wanted to see if anyone had any quick fixes

Comment: A quick fix, unfortunately no. You *could* go through a full reset, but because of its age it's likely to be an issue with the number of charge cycles the battery has gone through.